# Why does this while loop output very strange things?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I created some code that asks you for a variable amount, then asks you to input each variable and then stores it in a vector. The problem I am having, is that when you input something incorrect, and it asks you to try again, it either asks you to input the variable a certain amount of times depending on the characters you inputted which is really weird. I thought using `ssinput.clear();` would solve this but it doesn't.

For instance if I typed these things into the terminal below:

```
Please input variable 1: a

 ERROR, PLEASE ENTER ONLY VALID SYMBOLS
---------------------
Please input variable 1: 1
Please input variable 1: 3
Please input variable 1: 5
Please input variable 2: 1
Please input variable 3: 4
Please input variable 4: 3
Please input variable 5: 3
```

Overall it is being very sporatic and strange. My code is down below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int inputErrorMessage(){

    cout << "\n ERROR, PLEASE ENTER ONLY VALID SYMBOLS \n";
    cout << "--------------------- \n";

return 0;

}
int main(){

// Declare the variables, vectors, etc.
int varNum = 1;
int totVar = 5;
vector<double> userNums;
double input = 0;
string checkInput = "";
bool valid = false;
stringstream sstotVar;




    while(!valid){

        valid = true;

        // Ask the user for each variable, then record it into the array
        for (int i = 0; i < totVar; ++i) {
            cout << "Please input variable " << varNum << ": ";
            getline(cin, checkInput);
            stringstream ssinput(checkInput);
            ssinput >> input;

            if (ssinput.fail()) {
                inputErrorMessage();
                valid = false;
            }

            if (valid == true) {
                userNums.push_back(input);
                varNum++;
            }

                ssinput.clear();

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Minimal code.... You have two very large loops... shrink it to the one you are having the issue in and don't add all the libraries jesus...

Comment: Okay I will do that

Comment: It will make it so much easier to give you a nice answer.

Comment: Simply put: make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is done. You can look at it now.

Comment: Now it's unclear where you get the value of `totVar` from.

Comment: The original code I had up there changed that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays in these statements

```
vector <double> userNums;

double input = 0;
```

...

```
ssinput >> input;

if (ssinput.fail())
```

Checking to see if input contain decimal numbers.  That is way you cannot enter in characters.

Take a look at this.  Compiles and runs...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void inputErrorMessage(){

    cout << "\n ERROR, PLEASE ENTER ONLY VALID SYMBOLS \n";
    cout << "--------------------- \n";
}


int main(void) {

// Declare the variables, vectors, etc.
int varNum = 1;
int totVar = 5;
vector<string> userNums;
string input = "";
string checkInput = "";
bool valid = false;
stringstream sstotVar;




    while(!valid){

        valid = true;

        // Ask the user for each variable, then record it into the array
        for (int i = 0; i < totVar; ++i) {
            cout << "Please input variable " << varNum << ": ";
            getline(cin, checkInput);
            stringstream ssinput(checkInput);
            ssinput >> input;

            if (ssinput.fail()) {
                inputErrorMessage();
                valid = false;
            }

            if (valid == true) {
                userNums.push_back(input);
               varNum++;
            }

                ssinput.clear();

            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I could convert the vectors into numbers? I later use them to do some calculations.

Comment: What calculations are you planning on doing?  To store both the variables and the variable values, I would use two vectors.  Then again, I am not sure what exactly you want to do.